# How to fill a 20lb BBQ Propane tank with LPG?

Tags: propane

LPG filling stations fit [forklift tank filler valve threads (1-3/4 ACME)](https://propanewarehouse.com/shop/fittings/propane-tank-fill-valve/) not standard 20lb BBQ tanks threads. The 20lb BBQ threads are male 1-5/16″ ACME (OPD) threads, however most adaptors fit on the inside like this device designed to refill 1lb tanks from a standard 20lb:
[image]
Where can an adapter be found to simulate a forklift tank filler valve?

Comment: Just another question where OP's location may be of help. I know of somewhere in UK that probably makes just what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to adapt a 1" P.O.L. to a 1-3/4 ACME so that you can fill your BBQ propane tank with a different connector.

In that case you'd want something like this.

[image: adapter picture]
<sub>(source: [ebayimg.com](https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTE3MFgxNjAw/z/85sAAOSwDwtUptDL/$_57.JPG?set_id=880000500F))</sub>

[1-3/4" ACME to 1" POL Adapter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/181630492945?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82)

If you do get something like this, make sure it comes preassembled, or assemble carefully with *yellow* teflon or propane rated pipe dope.

Comment: You are right, The 1" POL end fits inside and the 1-3/4" ACME is the Forklift tank threads. 1-5/16″ ACME (OPD) is what a standard BBQ has.